# .keyup() on cloned input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone, keyup

I'm cloning input fields and then when I edit the cloned input field I'm trying to put the new values into an outside div as a text string. Thanks for your help in advance!

```
function cloneClue(target){
    clueCount++;
    var myClueField = $(target).prev().find('#textClue');
    var myClone = myClueField.clone().attr('id','textClue' + clueCount);
    var clueName = myClone.find('.clueName');
    var clueContent = myClone.find('.clueContent');
    var clueRemove = myClone.find('.clueRemove'); 
    var clueNamePreview = myClone.find('.clueNamePreview');
    var clueContentPreview = myClone.find('.clueContentPreview');

    clueName.attr('name', "clueName" + clueCount);
    clueName.attr('id', "clueName" + clueCount);
    clueContent.attr('name', "clueContent" + clueCount);
    clueContent.attr('id', "clueContent" + clueCount);
    clueRemove.attr('id', "clueRemove" + clueCount)

    clueNamePreview.attr('id', "clueNamePreview" + clueCount);
    clueContentPreview.attr('id', "clueContentPreview" + clueCount);

    clueRemove.click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    $('#clueField').append(myClone);
    myClone.show();
}
var clueCount = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {  

    $("#addTextClue").click(function(){
        cloneClue(this)
    });

    $('.clueName').keyup(function(){
        var nameVal = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().find('.clueNamePreview').html(nameVal);
    });

    $('.clueContent').keyup(function(){
        var contentVal = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().find('.clueContentPreview').html(contentVal);
    });

});
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/carney14/8yv5x7dg/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the .on for any element that is dynamically added to the DOM.

Change your jQuery to:

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".clueName", function() {
    ....
}
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you define you keyup listeners in your `document.ready` function. at this point your cloned elements aren't in your DOM, so there aren't any Listeners attached to your clones. Just move this part of code right after you appended your input clone like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8yv5x7dg/2/

Comment: Thank you so much I'm going this route!